# Matplotlib Kills shutsdown python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter-lab

I am running Python 3.10.13 from mamba miniforge3. I am having an issue where, no matter how I implement it, my instantiation of a matplotlib figure object crashes the kernel/ script/ terminal session. So, right after

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.show()
```

just these commands, generates a window and then the window shuts down and so does the kernel/terminal session. If it's an inline plot in jupyter, same thing happens. I have re-installed python and the same thing happens over and over.

Checking the back-end:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['backend']

>>'QtAgg'
```

Here are my system and python specs:

```
In [2]: platform.machine()
Out[2]: 'AMD64'

In [3]: platform.version()
Out[3]: '10.0.22621'

In [4]: platform.platform()
Out[4]: 'Windows-10-10.0.22621-SP0'

In [5]: platform.uname()
Out[5]: uname_result(system='Windows', node='name-3FW79K3', release='10', version='10.0.22621', machine='AMD64')

In [6]: platform.processor()
Out[6]: 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 141 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel'
```

```
     active environment : None
       user config file : C:\Users\name\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\name\miniforge3\.condarc
          conda version : 23.11.0
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.10.13.final.0
                 solver : libmamba (default)
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=x86_64
                          __conda=23.11.0=0
                          __cuda=12.2=0
                          __win=0=0
       base environment : C:\Users\name\miniforge3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : C:\Users\name\miniforge3\etc\conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\name\miniforge3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\name\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\name\miniforge3\envs
                          C:\Users\name\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/23.11.0 requests/2.31.0 CPython/3.10.13 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.22621 solver/libmamba conda-libmamba-solver/23.12.0 libmambapy/1.5.5
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

```
# packages in environment at C:\Users\...\miniforge3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
anyio                     4.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
archspec                  0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
argon2-cffi               23.1.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0          py310h8d17308_4    conda-forge
arrow                     1.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
asttokens                 2.4.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
async-lru                 2.0.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
attrs                     23.2.0             pyh71513ae_0    conda-forge
aws-c-auth                0.7.11               hcf9e330_1    conda-forge
aws-c-cal                 0.6.9                hd33547d_3    conda-forge
aws-c-common              0.9.12               hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
aws-c-compression         0.2.17               hd33547d_8    conda-forge
aws-c-event-stream        0.4.1                h875930a_2    conda-forge
aws-c-http                0.8.0                ha1a3518_2    conda-forge
aws-c-io                  0.14.0               hf372335_1    conda-forge
aws-c-mqtt                0.10.1               hda1dad8_0    conda-forge
aws-c-s3                  0.4.9                hef93162_0    conda-forge
aws-c-sdkutils            0.1.13               hd33547d_1    conda-forge
aws-checksums             0.1.17               hd33547d_7    conda-forge
aws-crt-cpp               0.26.0               hed7b20b_8    conda-forge
aws-sdk-cpp               1.11.210            h20b5662_10    conda-forge
babel                     2.14.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
beautifulsoup4            4.12.3             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
bleach                    6.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
boltons                   23.1.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
brotli                    1.1.0                hcfcfb64_1    conda-forge
brotli-bin                1.1.0                hcfcfb64_1    conda-forge
brotli-python             1.1.0           py310h00ffb61_1    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                hcfcfb64_5    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.25.0               hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2023.11.17           h56e8100_0    conda-forge
cached-property           1.5.2                hd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
cached_property           1.5.2              pyha770c72_1    conda-forge
certifi                   2023.11.17         pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.16.0          py310h8d17308_0    conda-forge
charset-normalizer        3.3.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
colorama                  0.4.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
comm                      0.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
conda                     23.11.0         py310h5588dad_1    conda-forge
conda-libmamba-solver     23.12.0            pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
conda-package-handling    2.2.0              pyh38be061_0    conda-forge
conda-package-streaming   0.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
contourpy                 1.2.0           py310h232114e_0    conda-forge
cycler                    0.12.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
debugpy                   1.8.0           py310h00ffb61_1    conda-forge
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
distro                    1.8.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.4                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
exceptiongroup            1.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_2    conda-forge
executing                 2.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
fmt                       10.1.1               h181d51b_1    conda-forge
fonttools                 4.47.2          py310h8d17308_0    conda-forge
fqdn                      1.5.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.12.1               hdaf720e_2    conda-forge
gettext                   0.21.1               h5728263_0    conda-forge
glib                      2.78.3               h12be248_0    conda-forge
glib-tools                2.78.3               h12be248_0    conda-forge
gst-plugins-base          1.22.8               h001b923_1    conda-forge
gstreamer                 1.22.8               hb4038d2_1    conda-forge
icu                       73.2                 h63175ca_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.6                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        7.0.1              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        7.0.1                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
importlib_resources       6.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2024.0.0         h57928b3_49840    conda-forge
ipykernel                 6.29.0             pyha63f2e9_0    conda-forge
ipython                   8.20.0             pyh7428d3b_0    conda-forge
ipywidgets                8.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
isoduration               20.11.0            pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.19.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    3.1.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
json5                     0.9.14             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jsonpatch                 1.33               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jsonpointer               2.4             py310h5588dad_3    conda-forge
jsonschema                4.21.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jsonschema-specifications 2023.12.1          pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jsonschema-with-format-nongpl 4.21.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter                   1.0.0             pyhd8ed1ab_10    conda-forge
jupyter-lsp               2.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_client            8.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_console           6.6.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              5.7.1           py310h5588dad_0    conda-forge
jupyter_events            0.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_server            2.12.5             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_server_terminals  0.5.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab                4.0.11             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_pygments       0.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_server         2.25.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_widgets        3.0.9              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.4.5           py310h232114e_1    conda-forge
krb5                      1.21.2               heb0366b_0    conda-forge
lcms2                     2.16                 h67d730c_0    conda-forge
lerc                      4.0.0                h63175ca_0    conda-forge
libabseil                 20230802.1      cxx17_h63175ca_0    conda-forge
libarchive                3.7.2                h313118b_1    conda-forge
libarrow                  14.0.2           he5f67d5_2_cpu    conda-forge
libarrow-acero            14.0.2           h63175ca_2_cpu    conda-forge
libarrow-dataset          14.0.2           h63175ca_2_cpu    conda-forge
libarrow-flight           14.0.2           h53b1db0_2_cpu    conda-forge
libarrow-flight-sql       14.0.2           h78eab7c_2_cpu    conda-forge
libarrow-gandiva          14.0.2           hb2eaab1_2_cpu    conda-forge
libarrow-substrait        14.0.2           hd4c9904_2_cpu    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0              21_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libbrotlicommon           1.1.0                hcfcfb64_1    conda-forge
libbrotlidec              1.1.0                hcfcfb64_1    conda-forge
libbrotlienc              1.1.0                hcfcfb64_1    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0              21_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libclang                  15.0.7          default_hde6756a_4    conda-forge
libclang13                15.0.7          default_h85b4d89_4    conda-forge
libcrc32c                 1.1.2                h0e60522_0    conda-forge
libcurl                   8.5.0                hd5e4a3a_0    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.19                 hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
libevent                  2.1.12               h3671451_1    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h8ffe710_5    conda-forge
libglib                   2.78.3               h16e383f_0    conda-forge
libgoogle-cloud           2.12.0               h39f2fc6_4    conda-forge
libgrpc                   1.59.3               h5bbd4a7_0    conda-forge
libhwloc                  2.9.3           default_haede6df_1009    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.17                 hcfcfb64_2    conda-forge
libjpeg-turbo             3.0.0                hcfcfb64_1    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0              21_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libmamba                  1.5.5                h3f09ed1_0    conda-forge
libmambapy                1.5.5           py310h04f2035_0    conda-forge
libogg                    1.3.4                h8ffe710_1    conda-forge
libparquet                14.0.2           h7ec3a38_2_cpu    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.39               h19919ed_0    conda-forge
libprotobuf               4.24.4               hb8276f3_0    conda-forge
libre2-11                 2023.06.02           h8c5ae5e_0    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h8d14728_1    conda-forge
libsolv                   0.7.27               h12be248_0    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.44.2               hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.11.0               h7dfc565_0    conda-forge
libthrift                 0.19.0               ha2b3283_1    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.6.0                h6e2ebb7_2    conda-forge
libutf8proc               2.8.0                h82a8f57_0    conda-forge
libvorbis                 1.3.7                h0e60522_0    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.3.2                hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.15                 hcd874cb_0    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.12.3               hc3477c8_0    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               hcfcfb64_5    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.4                hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
lzo                       2.10              he774522_1000    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7    conda-forge
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2    conda-forge
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2    conda-forge
mamba                     1.5.5           py310hd9d798f_0    conda-forge
markupsafe                2.1.4           py310h8d17308_0    conda-forge
matplotlib                3.8.2           py310h5588dad_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.8.2           py310hc9baf74_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
menuinst                  2.0.1           py310h00ffb61_0    conda-forge
miniforge_console_shortcut 1.0                  h57928b3_0    conda-forge
mistune                   3.0.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mkl                       2024.0.0         h66d3029_49657    conda-forge
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1    conda-forge
munkres                   1.1.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
nbclient                  0.8.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbconvert                 7.14.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbconvert-core            7.14.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbconvert-pandoc          7.14.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbformat                  5.9.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nest-asyncio              1.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
notebook                  7.0.7              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
notebook-shim             0.2.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.26.3          py310hf667824_0    conda-forge
openjpeg                  2.5.0                h3d672ee_3    conda-forge
openssl                   3.2.0                hcfcfb64_1    conda-forge
orc                       1.9.2                hf0b6bd4_0    conda-forge
overrides                 7.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
packaging                 23.2               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pandas                    2.2.0           py310hecd3228_0    conda-forge
pandoc                    3.1.3                h57928b3_0    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pathlib                   1.0.1           py310h5588dad_7    conda-forge
pcre2                     10.42                h17e33f8_0    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pillow                    10.2.0          py310h1e6a543_0    conda-forge
pip                       23.3.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pkgutil-resolve-name      1.3.10             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
platformdirs              4.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pluggy                    1.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ply                       3.11                       py_1    conda-forge
prometheus_client         0.19.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.42             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            3.0.42               hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
psutil                    5.9.8           py310h8d17308_0    conda-forge
pthread-stubs             0.4               hcd874cb_1001    conda-forge
pthreads-win32            2.9.1                hfa6e2cd_3    conda-forge
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyarrow                   14.0.2          py310hd0bb7c2_2_cpu    conda-forge
pybind11-abi              4                    hd8ed1ab_3    conda-forge
pycosat                   0.6.6           py310h8d17308_0    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pygments                  2.17.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 3.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyqt                      5.15.9          py310h1fd54f2_5    conda-forge
pyqt5-sip                 12.12.2         py310h00ffb61_5    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1              pyh0701188_6    conda-forge
python                    3.10.13         h4de0772_0_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-fastjsonschema     2.19.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-json-logger        2.0.7              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-tzdata             2023.4             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.10                    4_cp310    conda-forge
pytz                      2023.3.post1       pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pywin32                   306             py310h00ffb61_2    conda-forge
pywinpty                  2.0.12          py310h00ffb61_0    conda-forge
pyyaml                    6.0.1           py310h8d17308_1    conda-forge
pyzmq                     25.1.2          py310h2849c00_0    conda-forge
qt-main                   5.15.8              h9e85ed6_18    conda-forge
qtconsole-base            5.5.1              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
qtpy                      2.4.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
re2                       2023.06.02           hcbb65ff_0    conda-forge
referencing               0.32.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
reproc                    14.2.4.post0         hcfcfb64_1    conda-forge
reproc-cpp                14.2.4.post0         h63175ca_1    conda-forge
requests                  2.31.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
rfc3339-validator         0.1.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
rfc3986-validator         0.1.1              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
rpds-py                   0.17.1          py310h87d50f1_0    conda-forge
ruamel.yaml               0.18.5          py310h8d17308_0    conda-forge
ruamel.yaml.clib          0.2.7           py310h8d17308_2    conda-forge
send2trash                1.8.2              pyh08f2357_0    conda-forge
setuptools                68.2.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
sip                       6.7.12          py310h00ffb61_0    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
snappy                    1.1.10               hfb803bf_0    conda-forge
sniffio                   1.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
soupsieve                 2.5                pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
stack_data                0.6.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tbb                       2021.11.0            h91493d7_0    conda-forge
terminado                 0.18.0             pyh5737063_0    conda-forge
tinycss2                  1.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.13               h5226925_1    conda-forge
toml                      0.10.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tomli                     2.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tornado                   6.3.3           py310h8d17308_1    conda-forge
tqdm                      4.66.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.14.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
truststore                0.8.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
types-python-dateutil     2.8.19.20240106    pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing-extensions         4.9.0                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         4.9.0              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
typing_utils              0.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2023c                h71feb2d_0    conda-forge
ucrt                      10.0.22621.0         h57928b3_0    conda-forge
unicodedata2              15.1.0          py310h8d17308_0    conda-forge
uri-template              1.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   2.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
vc                        14.3                hcf57466_18    conda-forge
vc14_runtime              14.38.33130         h82b7239_18    conda-forge
vs2015_runtime            14.38.33130         hcb4865c_18    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.13             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
webcolors                 1.13               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1              pyhd8ed1ab_2    conda-forge
websocket-client          1.7.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.42.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
widgetsnbextension        4.0.9              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
win_inet_pton             1.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_6    conda-forge
winpty                    0.4.3                         4    conda-forge
xorg-libxau               1.0.11               hcd874cb_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                hcd874cb_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.6                h8d14728_0    conda-forge
yaml                      0.2.5                h8ffe710_2    conda-forge
yaml-cpp                  0.8.0                h63175ca_0    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.5                h63175ca_0    conda-forge
zipp                      3.17.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zstandard                 0.22.0          py310h0009e47_0    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.5                h12be248_0    conda-forge
```

Comment: Why is some of your text text, but other parts are images? Please no images.

Comment: Are images not allowed? It was quicker to just paste it. I wasn't aware images weren't allowed.

Comment: Images that need to be images are allowed. Images of text are heavily discouraged. Text should be copyable and sercheable, which images are not.